# Scrolling HTML Nested Tables

Tags: html, html-table, nested

How can I make a table which has sub/nested tables scrollable if given a max height? I do not want the thead to scroll with it. What I'm really looking for is some valid tag that I can wrap my s in, or some other markup that will work just as well as the this:

```
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- Insert valid tag here to wrap <tbody>s -->
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Val1</td>
            <td>Val2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sub-table">
            <td colspan="2">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Sub Column1</th>
                            <th>Sub Column2</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Sub Val1</td>
                            <td>Sub Val2</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Val1</td>
            <td>Val2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sub-table">
            <td colspan="2">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Sub Column1</th>
                            <th>Sub Column2</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Sub Val1</td>
                            <td>Sub Val2</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <!-- Insert valid close tag here -->
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want the TBODY of the nested tables to scroll, but the THEAD of the nested table to remain fixed, or should only the THEAD of the main table remain fixed?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, maybe try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pPuXL/1/

You need to display the TBODY elements as "block" or "inline-block" in order for overflow to work on it, as in the CSS example I posted.